# Cakephp How to set find() to return blank array instead of empty array when no result matched

Tags: arrays, cakephp, find

By default , cakephp would return empty array on `find()` when nothing founded.
but how to set it to show as blank array.

For example:

```
$customer = $this->Transaction->Customer->find(--conditions to return 0 result.--)
```

I want it to show as **blank array** like this.

```
array('Customer' => array('customer_id'=>null, 'name'=>null, 'lastname'=>null))
```

not just **empty** one like

`array()` or `null`

because I always got error shown in view that `$customer['Customer']['name']` is undefined index. and I don't like to use `isset()` or `is_null()` to check before every time.

Answer (score 2):

Use the afterFind callback method in your model. Something like this:

```
public function afterFind($results, $primary = false) {
    if (empty($results)) {
        $results = array('Customer' => array('customer_id'=>null, 'name'=>null, 'lastname'=>null))
    }
    return $results;
}
```

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/callback-methods.html

Answer (score 0):

If you really want/need to do this, you can use something like:

```
$default = array('Customer' => array('customer_id' => null, 'name'=>null, 'lastname' => null));
$customer = $this->Transaction->Customer->find(...)
$customer = array_merge($default, $customer);
```

This way, if the result is empty, it will use your default values.

However, this is not a good practice, because you might end up displaying `"Welcome, NULL"`, in the page. You should use `if (!empty($customer)) ...` in your view.

Also, in this example, are you using `find->('first')` ?

Comment: yes, I am using for find->('first') .and find->('all')

Comment: is my answer ok for you needs? if not, can you paste the code you are using in the  view?

Comment: your answer is ok for my problem , How ever the default array must changed everytime customer table updated. I ll try to find the way to solve this and merge array , Thank you.